# How do I disable a css class for a specific inner div tag when the div is a background box?

Tags: css, class, html, styles

I am using a div to style a background box for text and images.  I found a css class that enables a shadow when the whole box is hovered over.  However, because everything lies within that div, the text also has a shadow.  I don't know how to solve this issue other than maybe a better way to create a background box than what I'm doing?

Heres my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/dF9BF/

```
<div class= "shadow" style="position: absolute; width: 870px; height: 180px; background-    color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 6px;"><a href="LINK"</a>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding-left= "0px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style= "border: 0px; align: left; padding: 0px"><img src= "IMAGE" style= "height: 180px; align: left"></td>
<td style= "width: 50%; border: 0px; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px">
<div style="width: 310px; height: 35px; background-color: #3589d0; border: 0px; border-radius: 6px; align: left"><img class= "alignleft" align: left; src= "IMAGE" style= "margin-left: 5px" "margin-top: 10px" "padding-top: 15px" "padding-left: 10px" "padding-right: 0px" "align: left"><p style= "color: #ffffff; padding-top: 8px; padding-left: 0px">TEXT TEXT</p>
<br>
<br><p style= "color: #636363; font-size: 21pt"> MORE TEXT</p>
<br>
<p style= "color: #636363; font-size: 16pt"><em>TEXT
</em></p></div>
</td>
<td style="width: 100%; text-align: right; padding-right: 30px; padding-top: 0px;"><img src= "IMAGE" width= "100px">
<br><br>
<span style="font-size: 16pt; color: #025799;  margin-top: 10px">skdjfkjahf</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size: 16pt; color: #949494;">        <strike>asjdfklsajdf</strike></span>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.shadow {
width: 300px;
margin: 20px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 10px;
}

div.shadow:hover {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some sample code to show what you are working with. Specifically the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: create fiddle with your code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry Im new to this site and didnt know how to show my code.  http://jsfiddle.net/dF9BF/

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that this question has no code at the moment, I would say that there are two ways of doing what you want:

1. Making sure that the CSS properties you write only apply to the parent div (or)
2. Trying to unset the CSS properties for children elements.

Example of 1:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #styled { box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000; }
</style>
<div id="styled">
 <p>Test. This p will not have any shadows.</p>
</div>
```

Example of 2:

```
 <style type="text/css">
   #styled { font-size: 15px; }
   #styled p, #styled a, #styled div, #styled span { font-size: 10px; }
 </style>
 <div id="styled">
   <p>This p will have a font-size of 10px.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Can you see my code above and tell me how I would apply either of those solutions?

Comment: Make sure to validate your HTML. You have invalid HTML.